# how to add double value to pdfpcell

Tags: itext

```
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4); // 4 columns.

        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Medicine Name"));
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Quantity"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Price"));
        PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Total"));
        table.addCell(cell1);
        table.addCell(cell2);
        table.addCell(cell3);
        table.addCell(cell4);

         while(rs.next())   // fetch & writing records in pdf files
        {
            quan=rs.getInt("quantity");
            pric=rs.getDouble("price");
            total=quan*pric;


            cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(rs.getString("prodt_name")));
            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(quan));
            cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(rs.getString("price")));
            cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(total));
        table.addCell(cell1);
        table.addCell(cell2);
        table.addCell(cell3);
        table.addCell(cell4);

        }
```

total is double value and Paragraph consturctor doesn't accept double value.
so how can i insert double value in pdfpcell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `String.valueOf`

```
cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(total)));
```

`String.valueOf(double)` returns the string representation of the double argument. Please see the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double)) for more information.